# proving congruence question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $k\in \mathbb{N}.$ How do I prove that:$$\left(2^{{(3}^k)}\right)^2-2^{{(3}^k)}+1\equiv0\ \left(\bmod\ 3\right)$$

I have tried to use Fermat's little theorem, to prove that: $(2^k)^3\equiv 2^k\pmod{3}$, but from there I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: This is not true. Take k=2 for example or any even k.

Comment: @Forester oh sorry, I wrote it wrong. Let me fix it.

Comment: @Forester it has fixed!

Comment: Note that $2^{3^k}\not=(2^k)^3=2^{3k}$

Comment: @RobertZ now it's interesting to me, why $2^{3^k}≠ (2^k)^3\pmod{3}$? $3^k\equiv 3k\pmod{3}$ no?

Comment: Take $k=2$, $2^{3^2}\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $(2^2)^3\equiv 1\pmod{3}$

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- We know that $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$.
- $(-1)^r \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ if $r$ is odd. Try to identify the suitable $r$ in your context. From here, hopefully you can complete the task.

Comment: thanks! got it!